# Lucene Analyzer for a simple direct field search

Tags: java, search, lucene

I tried many lucene analzers and found keyword analyzer to be the best match for my requirement. I am using the same *keyword analyzer* for both updating the document and searching the same using QueryParser.
I want to search for the values with wildcard support.
For example : if a field "country" contains the value "india"
I can search for the same field as "ind*", "*ndi*", india etc.
I am getting the match for all other searches except the exact match.
ie. when i am searching the exact word (country:india), i am not getting any match.
If i am changing the same query as "country:india*" or "country:indi?", i am getting the 
match.
Also i have another doubt, if there is a country with the name "not", how can i search for the same.
I tried "country:"not"" and "country:\not". But both failed.
What is actually happening in both these cases?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have some whitespace or other extraneous characters after the country name.  You could either trim your input before adding it to Lucene, or implement a custom keyword analyzer, and add a [`TrimFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/TrimFilter.html), something like:

```
public final class CustomKeywordAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
  public CustomKeywordAnalyzer() {
  }

  @Override
  protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(final String fieldName, final Reader reader) {
    Tokenizer tokenizer = new KeywordTokenizer(reader)
    TokenStream filter = new TrimFilter(Version.LUCENE_43, tokenizer);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, filter);
  }
}
```

As far as searching for "not", it simply being lowercase should be adequate for it not to be interpreted as a boolean operator (`AND`, `OR`, and `NOT` operators must be uppercase, per [the documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Boolean_operators)).  Those words will get caught by a standard English `StopFilter` though, such as the one used by `StandardAnalyzer`.  Are you sure you are just using a `KeywordAnalyzer` when querying?

Barring that, though, the sure way to avoid query parser reserved words would be to just bypass the query parser entirely, and construct the query yourself:

```
Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("country", userQuery));
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. Though it does not solve my problem completely. It helped me a lot to understand a lot of things so that i can solve the rest myself. :)